# PHP - Backward compability during unserialize()

Tags: php, serialization, backwards-compatibility

I have an app, where user can save a serialized PHP object in a database.
Let's say it's a simple game.
The problem is: What if I made an update of this game and user will try to load his save?
Let's say I have a class like this:

```
class Car {
   private Engine $engine;
   private array $wheels;
   private Color $color;
   private int $id;

   // methods ommitted, as they donesn't matter
}
```

Assume that some user created new vehicle and save in on his account (as a serialized text in database).
After some time I decided to rebuild this class:
Let's say that I changed the $id property's name to $number, I removed $wheels property, I changed $engine property to be public and I added a $fuel property:

```
class Car {
    public Engine $engine;
    private Color $color;
    private int $number;
    private float $fuel;
}
```

If user will try to load his save now, the unserialize() function will not work.

**The question is:**

How to fix it? Which approach will be the best? Should I rebuild all saved data in my database during each update? Should I implement some __wakeup() or unserialize() methods in my classes? How to do it? Are there any good aproaches / best practices / pattern designs to solve this problem?

**// UPDATE:**
Ok, I found some solution. I don't know if its a good practice, but it (almost) work:
Inside of the new Car class I implemented a __wakeup() method like this:

```
 public function __wakeup() {
     unset($this->wheels);
     $this->number = $this->id;
     unset($this->id);
 }
```

As you can see, the first line unset $wheels, because this property no longer exist, and the two next lines change the $id to $number.
However, this line:

```
$this->number = $this->id;
```

produce an error:

```
Undefined property: Car::$id in ...
```

However I can see the value of this variable in the debbugger and in var_dump:

```
object(Car)[1]
  public string 'color' => string 'yellow' (length=6)
  private string 'engine' => string 'V4' (length=2)
  private int 'number' => *uninitialized*
  private float 'fuel' => float 50
  private 'wheels' => 
    array (size=4)
      0 => string 'a' (length=1)
      1 => string 'b' (length=1)
      2 => string 'c' (length=1)
      3 => string 'd' (length=1)
  private 'id' => int 88
```

So the **id** is stored somewhere in the memory, but I don't know how to access it. Any idea?

Comment: _"Should I rebuild all saved data in my database during each update?"_ - this definitely seems as the most robust solution. That way, transformation would be done only once.

Comment: Should you instead start looking into some database library (eloquent, doctrine etc.) to store data in the database.

Comment: That's a brilliant example for designing it with atomic values in DB and using some ORM for mapping DB rows into classes/models. Otherwise, you need to create a custom solution for mapping serialized data to classes and modifying it.

Comment: As others pointed out, you really should look into separating the data from your model. You're only running into these issues because you're using a suboptimal way of storing. Data that is spread across database tables is much easier to transform if need be.